# My Javascript is supposed to load one CSS on click, but loads both at the same time

Tags: javascript, html, css

When I launch my page, the css is totally messed up because my js is supposed to dynamically load css on click (mobile or standard website css). Currently, it just loads them both. Here's the code:

```
function loadjscssfile(filename, filetype)
{
    if (filetype=="css")
    {
        var fileref = document.createElement("link");
        fileref.rel= "stylesheet";
        fileref.type = "text/css";
        fileref.href = filename;
        document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(fileref)

    }
}
loadjscssfile("HCSS.css", "css")
```

I have two links on the site. One loads the mobile css, the other loads the standard website css. I have it linked like this:

```
 <a href="javascript:loadjscssfile ('HCSS.css','css')"> load hcss </a>
 <br/>
 <a href="javascript:loadjscssfile ('foundation.css','css')"> load mobile </a>
```

Comment: you're not "unloading" file X when you click to load file Y...

Comment: is the other css-file by default on the page and needs to be exchanged? Or do you initially have no css-file hardcoded into the page?

Comment: Are you sure? I don't see how it could--do you ever *unload*, or have a default?

Comment: @Sven Bieder yes there is an inital css already loaded on to the page how do i make it unload?

Comment: Can you post your html or an excerpt?

Comment: any specific part? its kind large its the main page for my school website

Comment: @ArkAngel with the removeChild() function

Comment: perhaps you'd consider using [alternate stylesheets](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/alternate/), which are built for exactly this purpose?

Comment: @SvenBieder thnx that fixed it :)

Answer (score 0):

What you are after is swapping css files, not just loading a new one. In jquery it would probabaly look something like this (code not tested):

```
function swapCssFiles(fileToLoad, fileToUnload) {
  $('head link[href="'+fileToUnload'"]')   // select the tag with css to unload
      .attr('href', fileToLoad);  // swap the href attribute with the file to load
}
```

This is off course possible with 'pure' javascript, but I'm to much a jQuery addict to tell you how. If you see how easy the syntax is, you can probably tell why.

Your links would look something like this:

```
<a href="javascript:swapCssFiles ('HCSS.css','default.css')"> load hcss </a>
```

I hope this is helpfull.

Note however that this is not the way I would approach this. If you want to target mobile devices with specific css, I would use mediaqueries to detect screensize, and not javascript.